# Make subplots using plotly express with values coming from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

Assuming I have a toy model `df` which lists the `model` of the car and `customer rating` of one car showroom.

```
CustomerID    Model       Cust_rating   

1             Corolla         A   
2             Corolla         B   
3             Forester        A   
4             GLC             C   
5             Xterra          A   
6             GLC             A
```

Using plotly express, I created pie charts of percentage of cars by model and by Cust_rating, respectively as two separate graphs:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.pie(df,names='Model',title='Proportion Of each Model')
px.pie(df,names='Cust_rating',title='Proportion Of each Rating')
```

Now, I want to create subplots, and all the ways of doing it using the documentation are throwing up errors:

```
ValueError: Trace type 'pie' is not compatible with subplot type 'xy'
at grid position (1, 1)
```

This is what I tried:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(values=df['Model']), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(values=df['Cust_rating']), row=1, col=2)
fig.update_layout(height=700, showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pie chart in a graph object requires a pair of labels and values. You must also specify the plot type in the subplot. See [this](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#subplots-types) for an example of a subplot type.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=("Model", "Rating"), specs=[[{'type': 'domain'},{'type': 'domain'}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=df['Model'].value_counts().index,
                     values=df['Model'].value_counts(),
                     legendgroup='model',
                     legendgrouptitle=dict(text='Model'),
                    ),
              row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=df['Cust_rating'].value_counts().index,
                     values=df['Cust_rating'].value_counts(),
                     legendgroup='rating',
                     legendgrouptitle=dict(text='Rating')),
              row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(height=400, width=600, showlegend=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use matplotlib and seaborn:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

if you want two and more plot use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20, 15))
```

And use ax=ax[0,1], row and col,

```
sns.boxplot(x = 'bedrooms', y = 'price', data = dataset_df, ax=ax[0,1])
sns.boxplot(x = 'floor, y = 'price', data = dataset_df,  ax=ax[0,2])
```